# Densityplot() of mean prices of 9 car brands

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot my data as a density plot, where there are 4 years 2003-2006.
part of my data looks like this:(county,year,x = mean price)

```
SFO          2003-01-01  464592.0
Alameda      2003-01-01  452649.4
Santa Clara  2003-01-01  767437.5
San Mateo    2003-01-01  543756.1
Napa         2003-01-01  691220.3
Contra Costa 2003-01-01  699626.9
```

I tried `densityplot( ~ price | county, housing)` but this is not what I want.
It gives me something like this.
[image]
And I couldn't make several lines in one density plot though I tried `lines()`

If I use `plot()`, it gives :
[image]
And this is not what I would like to have....

What I would like to have is a density plot with 6 lines in different colors that represent the county. X-axis would be the year while y-sxis would be the price.
[image]

Please help me out! Thanks!

Comment: If you could post an example of what sort of plot you *do* want to get, it would help us provide guidance.  If, e.g., you want a single chart with 6 curves, you probably want to use `plot` or `plot.density`

Comment: Another question: how do you turn time ("X axis is year") into density?  What do you really want?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft ,x axis is year since the data included 2003-2006, and I would like to plot the mean price for each year

Answer (score 0):

That is not a density plot. To plot the mean price for one county as a function of year, this would be a good excuse for you to learn to use `aggregate` or `plyr`.  To keep it as simple as possible, here's a clunky approach using no powerful functions.  Let's assume your dataframe has names "county" , "year" , and "price" .

```
sfomean <- sapply(unique(data$year), function(x) mean(data[(data$county=='SFO' & data$year==x),3])
```

Repeat for the other county names, or wrap the above line in

```
sapply(unique(data$county),function(y) sapply(unique(data$year), function(x) mean(data[(data$county==y & data$year==x),3]) )
```